# How to create a new db in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

If I use Mongoose in node.js I need to do:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB');
```

But what if I just installed mongodb and I don't have any DB at the moment? How can I create a new DB using mongoose in node.js before doing `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB')`? Or if there is no such `myDB` then it will create a new one? or will throw an error that there is no such a DB?

Comment: do I see there an API `createNewDB(...)` ? no. How do I create a new DB using mongoose in node.js?

Answer (score 21):

It should not throw any error. The moment you insert a document in any new collection of that DB, the collection and db will be created

Comment: So the is the URL specified only to parse the URL to mongodb server and the DB name? why don't do it separately?

Comment: This URL/mongoURI not only serves, specifying the server name but many other things. Check this out : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/connection-string/. Also you have to check your client-driver if they support all. Also, instead of passing the dbName to mongoURI, I am gussing you can do it separately. Atleast in java-driver, we can do it for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for me when trying to connect by mongoose.

!!!First of all you need to specify database even if you want to connect to default db (default db is 'admin') it's important!!!
Before I specified /admin db my data was mixing from several db.

You need to specify credentials (as username and password) for correct database (in my case `admin` (I never created `admin` db before, it's default db)).

But what to do if you want to connect to another database? You should feel `authSource` method in options of connection (specify another database in uri: mongodb://localhost:27017/database):

```js
mongoose.connect(
          mongoUri,
          {
            authSource: 'admin',
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            user: config.mongo.username,
            pass: config.mongo.password,
            serverSelectionTimeoutMS: 5000,
          },
          (err) => {
            if (err != null) {
              error('mongoose', err.message);
            } else {
              info('mongoose', 'mongoose connected');
            }
          },
        )
```

Answer (score -2):

In Mongoose, a new database record is created when `new mongoStore()` is invoked:

```
  app.use(session({
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    secret: pkg.name,
    store: new mongoStore({
      url: config.db,
      collection : 'sessions'
    })
  }));
```

or

```
const mongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
```

Comment: This answer appears to be specific to `express` and also does not answer the question very well.